# WooCommerce raw MySql query to insert new product

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building custom script that reads XML in order to insert new products. I am running script out of server where wordpress is installed so I need to perform raw mysql quires in order to insert new product.

Does someone knows is there way to insert a new WooCommerce product to database? I tried to find some resource on Internet but I couldn't find anything.

Best regards.

Comment: Why use SQL? A product is simply a post type and you can use WordPress' `wp_insert_post()`. Though you will need to mimic Woo's product meta data.

Comment: Since you are running the script out of the server where WordPress is installed, you can make use of  [WooCommerce REST API](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)

Comment: What i can help you is to know where the data is inserted (i mean in which tables)… First is inserted in `'posts'` table with a `'post_type' = 'product'` and with the id of this product it insert difference raws in `'postmeta` table… but i agree with @helgatheviking using `wp_insert_post()`